# Render django-filter(filterset) bar with Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-filter, django-crispy-forms

I created a filter bar (with filterset from the django-filter module), but I'm unable to render it with crispy forms.

Are crispy-forms compatible with django-filter? I tried it, and Crispy Forms works well with all my other forms and modelforms, but it seems like django-filter rejects to render in crispy-bootstrap.

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base/base1.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <form method="get">
            ****{{ myFilter.form}}****
    */tried also       {{ myFilter.form|crispy}} 
                       {{ myFilter.form.variablefieldhere|as_crispy_field}}** 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Filter.py:

```
import django_filters
from .models import log

class logFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = log
        fields = {
            'varfliedhere': ['icontains'],
            'varfliedhere': ['icontains'],
            'varfliedhere': ['icontains'],
            'Boolean varfliedhere': ['exact'],

        }
```

Should I try to set the FormHelper in forms? But in that case, how do I render it in Crispy Forms?

In the other forms, I rendered them 1 by 1 as:

```
{{ myFilter.form.variablefieldhere|as_crispy_field}}
```

which works, but I can't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: have you load crispy tag in html template? if not then add it in top of html template.

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, i actually loaded it (my bad didn't put all up in the description), but only partially works. After creating the functioning filterbar, I try to transform it from {{ myFilter.form}} to {{ myFilter.form|crispy}}, but it only renders the standard bootstrap version (the same I can get using widgets) and not crispy because it rejects any try I made to position the form elements . I usually state them 1 by one as{{form.variablefieldhere|as_crispy_field}} with a form-control type to give them a structure or inline as crispy function but behaves differently with the filter.

Answer (score 0):

As Your requirement is not clear to me. But i assume you want that all field in single row and you are using bootstrap templates for crispyform.

```
<form method="GET">
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0 ">
      {{myFilter.form.variablefieldhere1|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0 ">
      {{myFilter.form.variablefieldhere2|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0 ">
      {{myFilter.form.variablefieldhere3|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0 ">
      {{myFilter.form.variablefieldhere4|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class=" col-md-2 mb-0 ">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">search</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! In this case, I've been able to create succesfully a filterbar and partially render with crispy/bt5. I need to design it to have 1/2 rows with all the filter parameters. I tried before to use it as you wrote in your answer but it doesn't works and gives me "as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field". I'm unable to understand to how to make it work because all my other forms/modelforms (that i rendered as you wrote up but without "myFilter")work fine like this! Only when this filter is added it doesn't work. Hope I explained better what my current problem is

Answer (score 0):

Since I just ran into the same problem while trying to render individual filter fields: the issue might be that you initialize the lookup expressions in the Meta Class.

When I explicitly defined the variables in the class Body it worked for me.
Try this:

```
import django_filters
from .models import log

class logFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    varfield1 = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")
    varfield2 = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")
    
    class Meta:
        model = log
        fields = ["varfield1", "varfield2"]
```

And then in your HTML simply follow the answer of [khadim husen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102006/18342243).